# Should the question about making a living in real estate be reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question was asked yesterday and closed today:

[Why does it seem the best way to make a living is to invest in real estate?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/114986/10997)

Should it remain closed, or be reopened, and why?

Comment: I argued in the comments against closing it. I guess I should have edited it sooner.

Comment: Ben, have you voted to reopen? I don't see you in those 3 votes. Then one more after that.... Perhaps more importantly - I'd suggest some restraint before posting here.  The hold was crowdsourced, no mod action, and the reopens are already at 3. Strong chance it gets opened up again. The question if edited enough, just morphs to another question about real estate investing, which has probably been asked already. Nathan did give it a good edit, however, to delete some weird miserable life reference.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer My vote is the first reopen vote. (I don’t know what your view of the votes looks like, but I clearly see it in my list of reopen votes.) And I hope that this meta question will bring in the required reopen votes quickly. As I wrote in my answer, the question is an asset to our site. It has wonderful answers. It should not have been closed, and I hope it will be reopened in time to appear on the HNQ again.

Comment: Interesting. I see 3 names, not yours, who are the 3 current reopens. No big deal. We'll see if an HNQ status continues through a hold/reopen. Interesting.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I think it was premature for you to delete all the comments on the question before the question was reopened. You seem to think that it was wrong to open up this meta question to discuss, but you also are preventing discussion in the comments. I’m confused, because you have recommended to me in the past to post comments on closed questions to make my case for opening.

Comment: I've undeleted the 2 from you. (you are right, I wholesale deleted, but should have left yours)The rest were unhelpful, and did nothing to move the question forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to invite users to join me in voting to reopen this question. We don't close questions because they have a mistaken premise that we don't agree with. Indeed, the OP is asking the question because he had heard something related to personal finance that he is unsure about. And he is certainly not alone in wondering about this. We now have 8 great, objective, well-supported answers that many people in the future will find insightful and helpful. This is exactly the kind of question and answers we want on our site. It is on-topic, not too broad, and not primarily opinion-based.

Comment: The problem is that OP doesn't even care to cite the source of the claim, but writes 'it seems to' as if it was at least a common misconception.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo I believe in a comment the OP mentioned the writings of Robert Kiyosaki, but the comment was deleted by a mod.